# Finding an equivalent of $\int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{t}{t^2+1}\right)^n\ \mathrm dt$ when $n\to\infty$

Tags: integration, analysis

> I am looking for an equivalent of the following integral $$I_n = \int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{t}{t^2+1}\right)^n\ \mathrm dt$$ when $n \to + \infty$.

Do you have any hints?

I started by working according to if $n$ is odd.
Then, we can write $n=2k+1$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$. And by doing the substitution $u= 1+t^2$.
Hence, we have : $$I_n =\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(u-1)^k}{2u^{2k+1}}\ \mathrm du$$  we get by expanding the numerator : $$I_n =\sum_{l=0}^k   {k \choose l}(-1)^{k-l}\int_{0}^{1}u^{l-2k-1}\ \mathrm du.$$
I know how to integrate this, but I have no idea how to compute the sum we get after. And I think that I won't be able to do anything with this.

Comment: what do you mean by an equivalent of the integral?

Comment: Find a function $f$ depending of $n$ such that $I_n \sim f(n)$
What do you don't understand ? If I can clarify my words

Comment: You mean you just want an approximation or to find another form of the integral?

Comment: A quick upper bound is $2^{-n}$.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you want to find the asymptotics of the integral $I(n) = \int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{t}{t^2+1}\right)^n dt$.

The main term can be found in a standart way.

$$I(n)=\int_{0}^{1} e^{n\log\big(\frac{t}{t^2+1}\big)}dt=\frac{1}{2^n}\int_{0}^{1} e^{-n\log\big(\frac{t^2+1}{2t}\big)}dt=\frac{1}{2^n}\int_{0}^{1} e^{-n f(t)}dt$$
$$f(t)=\log\Big(\frac{t^2+1}{2t}\Big); \,\,\,\frac{df}{dt}(t)=\frac{t^2-1}{t(1+t^2)}=0 \,\, \text{at}\,\, t=1$$
$$\frac{d^2f}{dt^2}(t)=\frac{2t^4+2t^2-(t^2-1)(1+3t^2)}{t^2(1+t^2)^2}$$
$$f(1)=0;\,\,\frac{d^2f}{dt^2}(1)=1$$
Therefore,
$$f(t)=f(1)+\frac{df}{dt}(1)(t-1)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2f}{dt^2}(t-1)^2+... =\frac{1}{2}(t-1)^2+ ...$$
Making change $x=1-t$
$$I(n)\sim\frac{1}{2^n}\int_0^1e^{-n\frac{x^2}{2}}dx\sim\frac{1}{2^n}\int_0^\infty e^{-n\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2^{n+1/2}\sqrt n}$$